# android use HttpPost and StringEntity

Tags: android, android-json, androidhttpclient

It's my first project. When i use **Post**,I can't send the data to server.

Here is my code:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try
        {          json.put("_username", mUsername);
                   json.put("_password", mPassword);
                   String s=json.toString();
                   System.out.println("string: " + s);
                   StringEntity se = new StringEntity( s,HTTP.UTF_8);
                   System.out.println("0.string: " + se);
                   se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
                   System.out.println("1.string: " + se);
                   httpRequest.setEntity(se);
```

And it `catch (Exception e)`
Here is **logcat**:

```
07-05 13:09:57.731 16809-16809/com.ad_imagine.jsonconnection I/System.out: string: {"_username":"lorem@ipsum.fr","_password":"aze"}
07-05 13:09:57.733 16809-16809/com.ad_imagine.jsonconnection I/System.out: 0.string: org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@3117948
07-05 13:09:57.733 16809-16809/com.ad_imagine.jsonconnection I/System.out: 1.string: org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@3117948
07-05 13:09:57.768 16809-16809/com.ad_imagine.jsonconnection I/System.out: 6.Exception: null
```

What is `org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@3117948`? Why 0.string is not correct?

Comment: Why are you sending JSON data but tell the server its form-data?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want your POST request to look like?

Answer (score 0):

> What is `org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@3117948`?

`org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@3117948` is the result of `se.toString()`. StringEntity does not seem to override `toString()` so the implementation of `Object.toString()` is used which just returns `<FullyQualifiedClassName>@<hashCode>`

> Why 0.string is not correct?

You can't tell its not correct. You have to read from `se.getContent()`

Comment: You don't have to add `se.toString()`, the compiler added that for you.

`System.out.println("0.string: " + se);` and `System.out.println("0.string: " + se.toString());` are exaclty the same.

You have to call se.getContent() and read from it.

Comment: but how to change the code? I want `se` to be `_username=lorem@ipsum.fr&_password=aze`,then i can send it to server

Comment: The content of `se` is `{"_username":"lorem@ipsum.fr","_password":"aze"}`

Comment: i have added getContent(), it changes to ` 0.string: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@714c3e1`

Comment: The class `StringEntity` wraps a String (in your case some JSON data in `s`) in an `InputStream` (that object returned by `se.getContent()`). If you wan't to get the String back from the `InputStream` look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string